# How to parse Command Line Arguments with arbitrary string

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I'm trying to create a script that has an option that will contain arbitrary text (including spaces) surrounded by quotes and this is proving difficult to search for and implement.

Basically the behavior I would like to have is `docker_build_image.sh -i "image" -v 2.0 --options "--build-arg ARG=value"`, this will be a helper script for simplifying versioning docker images with our build server.

The closest I've come to successfully grabbing the `--options` value gives me an error from getopt, "unrecognized option '--build-arg ARG=value'.

The full script is below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o noclobber -o nounset -o pipefail
params="$(getopt -o hi:v: -l help,image:,options,output,version: --name "$0" -- "$@")"
eval set -- "$params"

show_help() {
cat << EOF
Usage: ${0##*/} [-i IMAGE] [-v VERSION] [OPTIONS...]

Builds the docker image with the Dockerfile located in the current directory.

    -i, --image         Required. Set the name of the image.
    --options           Set the additional options to pass to the build command.
    --output            (Default: stdout) Set the output file.
    -v, --version       Required. Tag the image with the version.
    -h, --help          Display this help and exit.
EOF
}

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    case $1 in
        -h|-\?|--help)
            show_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        -i|--image)
            if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                IMAGE=$2
                shift
            else
                echo -e "ERROR: '$1' requires an argument.\n" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;        
        -v|--version)            
            if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                VERSION=$2
                shift
            else
                echo -e "ERROR: '$1' requires an argument.\n" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        --options)
        echo -e "OPTIONS=$2\n"
            OPTIONS=$2
        ;;
        --output)            
            if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                BUILD_OUTPUT=$2
                shift
            else
                BUILD_OUTPUT=/dev/stderr
            fi
        ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
        ;;
        *)
            echo -e "Error: $0 invalid option '$1'\nTry '$0 --help' for more information.\n" >&2
            exit 1
        ;;
    esac
shift
done

echo "IMAGE: $IMAGE"
echo "VERSION: $VERSION"
echo ""

# Grab the SHA-1 from the docker build output
ID=$(docker build ${OPTIONS} -t ${IMAGE}  . | tee $BUILD_OUTPUT | tail -1 | sed 's/.*Successfully built \(.*\)$/\1/')

# Tag our image
docker tag ${ID} ${IMAGE}:${VERSION}
docker tag ${ID} ${IMAGE}:latest
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you seem to be using the "enhanced" getopt (from util-linux or Busybox), just handle `options` like you handle the others that take an argument (`image` and `version`). I.e. add the colon marking a mandatory argument to the option string that goes to getopt, and pick the value off of `$2`.

I think the error you get comes from `getopt`, since it's not told that `options` takes an argument, and so it tries to interpret `--build-arg ARG=value` as a long option (it does start with a double-dash).

```
$ cat opt.sh
#!/bin/bash
getopt -T
if [ "$?" -ne 4 ]; then
    echo "wrong version of 'getopt' installed, exiting..." >&2
    exit 1
fi 
params="$(getopt -o hv: -l help,options:,version: --name "$0" -- "$@")"
eval set -- "$params"

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
    case $1 in
        -h|-\?|--help)
            echo "help"
            ;;
        -v|--version)            
            if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                echo "version: <$2>"
                shift
            fi
            ;;
        --options)            
            if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                echo "options: <$2>"
                shift
            fi
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

$ bash opt.sh --version 123 --options blah --options "foo bar"
version: <123>
options: <blah>
options: <foo bar>
```

Comment: I was misunderstanding how ':' worked, I thought it made the option required but it just means the options has a required variable.  The above now works, thanks!

Comment: @GregB, ah, no, _that_ logic you need to implement yourself, just check that `$IMAGE` and `$VERSION` aren't empty after the loop. (Or rather, if an empty value is valid, set a flag when they are set.)