# Multichar options in Unix sysytems

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, getopts

I have a usecase wherein I need to support multiple character option. Currently I am using single character option for getopts. Multi-character option is desirable.What's the best way of doing this? I came across articles implementing a manual parser for this usecase,but is that optimal with respect to performance.

I want something like -ab to be treated as -ab only and not -a -b . Also is it a good coding practice?

This is just done to make the options more meaningful as opposed to single char options which do not provide complete information about that option.

Important:  I also want optargs with these multi-character options .Example -ab "sdfd" .

Here's the code

```
while getopts ":s:p:q:j:o" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    s)
      only_save=TRUE
      new_tok=$OPTARG
      ;;
    p)
      only_upload_enum_json=TRUE
      enum="job_status"
      new_tok=$OPTARG
      ;;
    q)
      only_upload_enum_json=TRUE
      enum="lifecycle_state"
      new_tok=$OPTARG
      ;;
    j)
      only_download_enum_json=TRUE
      enum=$OPTARG
      ;;
    o)
      only_download=TRUE
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "   -s <token>"
      echo "   -p <token>"
      echo "   -q <token>"
      echo "   -j <enum_name>"
      echo "   -o <no value needed>"
      exit;
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Here for job_status its desirable to use -js instead of -p to make it more meaningful.and similarly for lifecycle_state

Comment: *but is that optimal with respect to performance.* If you care about the performance of command line parsing, writing a shell script is a non-starter. Usually you don't really care how many micro- to milliseconds your program needs to parse a command line – so if this is an important metric in your program, you **really** need to explain *what* performance you're looking for. The fact that you'd only need command line parsing when you start a new process means that you're worrying about a really small computational load (parsing) with a really large one (forking a shell process)!

Comment: *Also is it a good coding practice?* do you mean a good command line convention? Because *good coding practice* refers to the way you implemented some algorithm in code, and you're not sharing any code with us.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've added the code now.

Comment: You can use the external program [`getopt`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/util-linux/getopt.1.en.html) (the [example code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-example.bash) is quite helpful). There is some controversy around getopt because there are various implementtions of it, some are buggy. If you can stick to GNU getopt, you should be OK

Comment: @glennjackman I want to stick to getopts only as its production code and don't want bugginess. Is there any way out?

Comment: No. getopts only supports single-character options. I use getopt in production code.

Comment: any manual parser to suit my usecase with optargs as well?

Comment: You would make `-a` an option that requires an argument, and throw an error if the argument is not `b`.

Comment: @glennjackman as I said i'm already accepting an argument with -ab .so -a accepting b as argument means I would not be able to use my additional argument.  I want something like -ab $OPT_ARG to be supported

Comment: Then you need to pick a different tool that can support that usage. Bash can't do it.

Comment: @glennjackman, it's from util-linux, not GNU. But yes, usually available mostly on Linuxen. Busybox has a similar implementation to the util-linux one, it looks like it also supports long options. The "traditional" implementations suck, they can't handle args with whitespace correctly.

Comment: @VatsalAMehta, note that GNU-style long options are `--option`, i.e. with a double dash. Those are likely the ones most commonly used, so you might consider using the same. Of course, X programs have options like `-geometry`, so it's not like single-dash long options don't exist. They're not that easy to combine with short options, though, if you still want to be able to stack `-a -b -c` into `-abc`, which people will likely expect if those short options exist.

Comment: `getopt` with long options: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310890/170373

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm using `getopt`, not `getopts`, in a function called `option_handling`, see my shell-script-template below.

If you want to pass args with your options you can:

Let's say your option is -z 'something'...

```bash
[...]
--options hVvz:
[...]
-z)args="$2"; shift2;;
```

You want to hab a look at `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash` --that should come preinstalled.

Here's the template:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash - 
#===============================================================================
#
#          FILE: <<filename here>>
#
#         USAGE: 
#
#   DESCRIPTION: 
#
#       OPTIONS: ---
#  REQUIREMENTS: ---
#          BUGS: ---
#         NOTES: ---
#        AUTHOR: 
#  ORGANIZATION: 
#       CREATED: 
#       LICENSE: BSD-3-CLAUSE
#      REVISION:  ---
#===============================================================================

#=== Init ======================================================================
set -o nounset   # exit on unset variables.
set -o errexit   # exit on any error.
set -o errtrace  # any trap on ERR is inherited
#set -o xtrace    # show expanded command before execution.

unalias -a       # avoid rm being aliased to rm -rf and similar issues
LANG=C           # avoid locale issues
VERBOSE=         # Don't be verbose, unless given '-v'-option

ScriptVersion="1.0"

trap "cleanup" EXIT SIGTERM

#=== Functions =================================================================
usage (){
  echo "

  Usage :  ${0##/*/} [options] [--]

  Options:
  -h|--help     Display this message
  -V|--version  Display script version
  -v|--verbose  Print informational text

  "
  exit 0
}    # ----------  end of function usage  ----------

option_handling () {
  # see /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash
  OPTS=$(getopt --name "$0" \
    --options hVv \
    --longoptions help,version,verbose \
    --shell bash \
    -- "$@") \
    || (echo; echo "See above and try \"$0 --help\""; echo ; exit 1)

  eval set -- "$OPTS"
  unset OPTS

  while true ; do
    case "$1" in
      -h|--help)
        usage
        ;;
      -V|--version)
        echo "$0 -- Version $ScriptVersion"; exit 0
        ;;
      -v|--verbose)
        VERBOSE=true
        shift
        ;;
      --)
        shift ; break
        ;;
      *)
        echo "I don't know what to do with \"$1\". Try $0 --help"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
  done
} # ----------  end of function option_handling  ----------

cleanup () { # Will be called by the trap above, no need to call it manually.
  :
} # ----------  end of function cleanup  ----------

# see https://github.com/markgraf/flatten.sh about this
. ~/scripting/library.bash/lazy.lib

#=== Main ======================================================================
main () {
  option_handling "$@"

  

} # ----------  end of function main  ----------

main "$@"

#=== End =======================================================================
```